# Separating letters in string with spaces (loops only)

Tags: java, string, loops, split

I am suppose to make this loop program, that when you enter a word it separates each single letter.

For example, I would enter `blue`, then it should RETURN `b l u e`.

I want to start it as a for loop, but I have no clue on how to space each letter. Any tips, clues anyone?

This is my code so far. (As you can see this is empty, I have been stressing over this for hours.)

```
public static String split(String str){

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `String` in Java is a char sequence. Simply treat is like that, and run a for loop as follows:

```
String str = "blue";
char[] a = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) System.out.println(a[i]);
```

Produces:

```
b
l
u
e
```

If you want to return the characters, then it's a one liner: `return str.toCharArray()`.

Comment: i am supose to have a return value not have a system.out.println.0.0
how am i suppose to do that

Comment: That was already included, but I added a line to make it explicit ... hope it helps :-)